# Blazor Syncfusion Multiselect: How to handle huge amount of data in Blazor Syncfusion Multiselct?

Tags: blazor, multi-select, syncfusion

I have to select some employees from a Syncfusion Multiselect in Blazor WASM. When I use it with 5000 employee data, it works so slow or crashes. I search my employee with FullName or Personnel Number(FullInfo is FullName and Personnel Number together). I try to send my search string after 4 string to the backend and receive result and set it to datasource and refresh the dropdown list, but it also not work efficiently and I think this isn't the best practice for this issue.

```
<SfMultiSelect 
@ref="mulObj"
TValue="List<string>"
TItem="EmployeeQueryModel"
Mode="VisualMode.Box"
EnableRtl="true"
Query="LocalDataQuery"
EnableVirtualization="true"
Placeholder="Please choose your employees..."
AllowFiltering="true"
DataSource="employeesDropDown"
@bind-Value="CommandModel.MultiSelectEmployees">

  <MultiSelectFieldSettings Value="PersonnelCode" Text="FullInfo">
  </MultiSelectFieldSettings>
  <MultiSelectEvents TItem="EmployeeQueryModel" TValue="List<string>"
      ValueRemoved="@ValueRemovedHandler"
      Filtering="@FilteringHandler"
      OnValueSelect="@OnValueSelectHandler"
      Cleared="@ClearedHandler">
  </MultiSelectEvents>
</SfMultiSelect>

@code { 
...
    private void OnValueSelectHandler(SelectEventArgs<EmployeeQueryModel> args)
    {
        selectedEmployees.Add(args.ItemData);
    }

    private void ValueRemovedHandler(RemoveEventArgs<EmployeeQueryModel> args)
    {
        selectedEmployees.Remove(args.ItemData);
    }

    private void ClearedHandler(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        selectedEmployees = new List<EmployeeQueryModel>();
    }
       
    private async Task FilteringHandler(FilteringEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Text.Length >= 4)
        {
            args.PreventDefaultAction = true;

            employeesDropDown = GetFilteredEmployees(args.Text);
            employeesDropDown.AddRange(selectedEmployees);
            await mulObj.FilterAsync(employeesFiltered, LocalDataQuery);
            await mulObj.RefreshDataAsync();
        }
    }
...
```

How can I implement Blazor Syncfusion MultiSelect in a better way and improve performance of my app?
How to use Blazor Syncfusion MultiSelect in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AsAsyncEnumerable` in your query to achieve the better performance, such as bellow:

```
    public IAsyncEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return _dbContext.Employees                
            .AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
```

Async Streams or IAsyncEnumerable provides a way to iterate over an IEnumerable collection asynchronously.

If you'd like to receive each part of the data as soon as it arrives, rather than waiting for the complete data to be available. At the same time, you wouldn't like to block the CPU while waiting for the chunks of data. This is where IAsyncEnumerable can help you.

For more info you can refer to [IAsyncEnumerable with yield in C#](https://code-maze.com/csharp-async-enumerable-yield/)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to call the RefreshDataAsync method externally to refresh the popup element.

find the code example on the razor page:

```
<SfMultiSelect @ref="DDLObj" AllowFiltering="true" TValue="string[]" TItem="Record" Placeholder="e.g. Item 1" DataSource="@Records" Query="@LocalDataQuery" PopupHeight="130px" EnableVirtualization="true">
<MultiSelectFieldSettings Text="Text" Value="ID" />
<MultiSelectEvents TValue="string[]" TItem="Record" Filtering="OnFilter"></MultiSelectEvents>
```

```
@code {
SfMultiSelect<string[], Record> DDLObj;
public Query LocalDataQuery = new Query().Take(6);
public class Record
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    this.Records = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000).Select(i => new Record()
        {
            ID = i.ToString(),
            Text = i.ToString(),
        }).ToList();
}



async Task OnFilter(FilteringEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Text.Length >= 4)
    {
        args.PreventDefaultAction = true;
        Query query = new Query().Where(new WhereFilter()
            {
                Field = "ID",
                value = args.Text,
                Operator = "startswith",
                IgnoreCase = true
            });

        await this.DDLObj.FilterAsync(this.Records, query);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I use this solution before, there is a delay when I'm trying to filtering data when I have too much records.